# Display Value of timer - VB

Tags: vb.net

I can't figure out how to simply display to value of a timer after it's stopped in VB.

I tried stuff like `MsgBox(Val(Timer2))` but it's not that simple apparently.

Comment: What exactly do you want to see?

Comment: try MsgBox(Timer2.Interval) to see the interval

Comment: Basically Its a small racing game so i want to start at 0 and once a certain condition is met the timer would stop and display the time it took for the race.

Comment: Do you mean a timer as in this class, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx? Because other than the timer Interval, a timer doesn't have a value.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the stopwatch class would work for you:

```
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    sw.Start()
    'do something, for example:
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    sw.Stop()
    MessageBox.Show(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this,

```
Dim StartTime = DateTime.Now()

'Do race stuff



Dim EndTime = DateTime.Now()

Dim ElapsedSeconds = EndTime.Subtract(StartTime).TotalSeconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Timers don't do that. But you can use various date/time functions to do the same thing.

```
Dim startTime As DateTime
Dim elapsed As DateTime
' ...
Timer2.Start()
startTime = Now

' after race finishes, then:
elapsed = Now - startTime
```

This gives you a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) object.

or

```
Dim startTime As Integer = Environment.TickCount
' ...
Dim elapsed As Integer = Environment.TickCount - startTime
```

This gives you an overall time in milliseconds.